# How to pop unknown argument, then call another function with the rest of unknown arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm trying to make a function "a" that will take minimum 1 argument in JavaScript.

This function will extract the 1st argument out, then call another function "b" with the rest of the arguments.

Something like this:

```
var a = function() {

    var name = arguments[0];   // get argument1       

    console.log("Running ", name);   

    b(<<argument2, argument3... to rest>>>);
}


var b = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

However I'm really unsure how to write the line:

```
b(<<argument2, argument3... to rest>>>);
```

The "arguments" can be converted into array, and hence can pop out the first argument. However I'm really unsure how to call the function b() with the rest of arguments dynamically.

Is there such function call like `b(arguments=myArr);` in JS ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know about the `.apply()` function, and/or [`...` spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)?

Comment: ^thanks for this, learning it now, definitely the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var a = function() {
  var name = arguments[0]; // get argument1
  console.log("Running ", name);
  var argsForB = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // converts arguments to an array and removes the first param
  b.apply(null, argsForB); // calls b sending all the other params. Note that `this` inside b will be `null`. You can replace it with any other value.
}
var b = function() { 
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps pass an array to function "a", retrieve the first value as you had planned, use [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) on the array, and then pass the remaining array to function "b".

```
var a = function(arguments) {
    var name = arguments[0];   // get argument1       
    console.log("Running ", name);   
    arguments.shift();
    b(arguments);
}

var b = function(arguments) {
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

a([1,2,3,4]);
```

Results in the console logging:

```
Running 1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with ES6， you can use ... to extract array 

  var a = function() {

        var name = arguments[0];   // get argument1       

        console.log("Running ", name);   
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.shift()
        b(...args);
    }


    var b = function() {
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `arguments` support `.shift()`? (If so, why not `name = arguments.shift()`)?

Comment: if you're going the ES2015+ route, why not `var a = function(name, ...args) { b(...args); }`

Comment: emmm,it seems I forgot add Array.prototype.slice.call()

Comment: ^after reading spread syntax, this is definitely an elegant way to go. However I need to support IE users; and IE so conveniently neglects this (in the doc @nnnnnn gave in original post comment). So sadly need to give it a pass.